# How to use orderby in Azure containerregistry REST API

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I'm using the Azure REST API to retrieve tags from an Azure Container Registry.
I want to retrieve newest 10 results. The top 10 can be achieved by adding ?n=100, however I get the oldest 10 tags.

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/tag/getlist, I should be able to add `orderby` to my url as well, however I cannot get it to work.

I can achieve this successfully using the Azure CLI, using this command:
`az acr repository show-tags -n [registry] --repository [repository] --top 10 --orderby time_desc`

In the application itself I need to use the REST API. I've tried several options, including `time_desc` and `time desc`, but cannot find a working solution.

https://registry.azurecr.io/v2/repository/tags/list?n=10&orderby=time_desc

Comment: I think it's just a typo of all your tries, but in your CLI example you wrote `--orderby time_asc` and in your API sample you wrote `orderby=time_desc`

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing it out! It should be descending in both cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can use the parameter `--debug` to get the right REST API format from the CLI command:

```
az acr repository show-tags -n [registry] --repository [repository] --top 10 --orderby time_desc --debug
```

Finally, you can find the format like this:

[image]

I also do the test on my side, and here is the screenshot of the result:

[image]

Note: you can use the basic Auth with the username and password of the ACR.

Comment: Thank you! Not just an answer to my question, but also a generic way of finding a solution for Azure REST API questions. Thanks!